# Sum by_group with x variables in r

Tags: r, sum

I have a problem and I need your help please.

I try to sum by group in r without success. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.
I have a grouped data frame.

```
head(my_data_frame)
Source: local data frame [6 x 329]
Groups: x, y [2]
```

Here an example of data frame

```
        x     y      a  
      (int) (int) (dbl)  
1  10101101    11     1   
2  10101101    11     1   
3  10101101    11     0   
4  10101101    11     0   
5  10101101    12     1   
6  10101101    12     1   
7  10101101    12     1   
8  10101101    21     1   
9  10101101    21     0   
10 10101101    21     0
```

I need sum 'a' over 'x' and 'y' to obtain 'b'
here is the code that I used but without success

```
test_df <- my_data_frame %>%
 group_by(x, y) %>%
 mutate(b = sum(a))
```

Here is and example of what I need (but the code above don't work in the way that I need)

```
        x     y     a      b
      (int) (int) (dbl)  (dbl)
1  10101101    11     1   2
2  10101101    11     1   2
3  10101101    11     0   2
4  10101101    11     0   2
5  10101101    12     1   3
6  10101101    12     1   3
7  10101101    12     1   3
8  10101101    21     1   1
9  10101101    21     0   1
10 10101101    21     0   1
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the expected output?  If the last is what your expected, it works for me.  Can you try `%>%dplyr::mutate(b=sum(a))`

Comment: Yes it is the last one. Thanks!!! I add the 'dplyr::...' to the code and it's works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mutate` is one of the function that is found in more than one package i.e. in `plyr` and `dplyr`.  So, if both packages are loaded, there is a chance that `mutate` from `dplyr` got masked by the `plyr` version of `mutate`.  In order to rectify it, we can use `dplyr::mutate`

```
test_df <- my_data_frame %>%
                  group_by(x, y) %>%
                  dplyr::mutate(b = sum(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

aggregate should easily solve this:

```
merge(my_data_frame, setNames(aggregate(a ~ x + y, data = my_data_frame, sum), c('x', 'y', 'b')), all.x = TRUE)
```